# Cover letter with Sender and Recipient on the left-hand-side

Tags: letters, covers, letterspacing, letterhead

I would like to use the documentclass **letter** but only moving the sender -field to the left-hand-side.

Minimal example from [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Letters):

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\signature{Joe Bloggs}
\address{21 Bridge Street \\ Smallville \\ Dunwich DU3 4WE}
\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Director \\ Doe \& Co \\ 35 Anthony Road
\\ Newport \\ Ipswich IP3 5RT}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam:}

I am writing to you on behalf of the Wikipedia project (http://www.wikipedia.org/),
an endeavour to build a fully-fledged multilingual encyclopaedia in an entirely
open manner, to ask for permission to use your copyrighted material.

% The \ldots command produces dots in a way that will not upset
% the typesetting of the document.
\ldots

That said, allow me to reiterate that your material will be used to the noble end of
providing a free collection of knowledge for everyone; naturally enough, only if you
agree. If that is the case, could you kindly fill in the attached form and post it
back to me? We shall greatly appreciate it.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

I look forward to your reply.

\closing{Yours Faithfully,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Example what I have now for English speakers i.e. the letter's format:

[image]

This is what I need for Finnish speakers

[image]

where you have the sender and recipient on the left-hand-side but otherwise the same.

I have tried the documentclass **\documentclass[a4paper]{scrlttr2}** but it is too overkill - increasing linespace and puts an extra line  for name and address.

### Official model of Finnish Document Class, here original [source](https://wiki.uef.fi/download/attachments/12845366/mallilomake.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1281010819000&api=v2)

This part is made for the request of Johannes B in his comment.

The document standard is called "Asiakirjastandardi" in Finnish, wiki [here](http://fi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asiakirjastandardi). 
The document is classified by the document model type **SFS 2487** (*asiakirjamalli* in Finnish).
It is maintained by **Suomen Standardisoimisliitto SFS ry** and online [here](https://wiki.uef.fi/display/opkmateriaalit/Lomakkeen+asettelumalli+%28asiakirjastandardi%29).

Translations to the file

[image]

and 2nd page

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by *increasing linespace and puts an extra line for name and address*? See the thing is, instead of saying it doesn't work, you could link me to some finish specifications or norms, and i will take care that there will be  `lco` available for finnish users soon.

Comment: @Johannes_B I got releveant answers from the authories on the matter. They provided me the model which the document has to follow. Can you make the **lco** or do you need my help for that? See the edit of the body of my question.

Comment: This looks a bit like the standard *get out your typewriter* and *hit enter twice* kind of norm. We have something similar in Germany as well. You clarified the horizontal positions, but what about the vertical ones? When you say *two enters*, does that mean a blank line in the output? What is the page size? Is it usual for your letters to have sections?

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes, two enters mean a blank line in the output. Page size is A4. Letter can a be document so it can have sections. But it is not needed. I would put sections optional and the horizontal left-padding too optional.

Comment: I just had an awful lot of fun using google translate trying to understand the matter of the linked picture/pdf. As it is obviously written for typewriter users, i don't recommend following the rules straight ahead for use with LaTeX and instead make it logically and look good. The recipient will thank you.

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes, I agree with you! Feel free to send me your result such that I can forward it to people who can confirm its validity. I do my best to get an official acceptance for your work.

Comment: I am a bit busy, but it isn't that far away from classic DIN, which is `scrlttr2` defaultdue to its german origins. Give me a bit of time, i'll write something down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to patch `\opening`:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\opening}[1]{\ifx\@empty\fromaddress
  \thispagestyle{firstpage}%
    {\raggedleft\@date\par}%
  \else  % home address
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    {\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}\ignorespaces
      \fromaddress 
      \end{tabular}
      \par\nopagebreak
      \vspace{2\parskip}%
      \raggedleft\begin{tabular}{l@{}}\ignorespaces
      \@date 
      \end{tabular}\par}%
  \fi
  \vspace{2\parskip}%
  {\raggedright \toname \\ \toaddress \par}%
  \vspace{2\parskip}%
  #1\par\nobreak}
\makeatother
\signature{Joe Bloggs}
\address{21 Bridge Street \\ Smallville \\ Dunwich DU3 4WE}
\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Director \\ Doe \& Co \\ 35 Anthony Road
\\ Newport \\ Ipswich IP3 5RT}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam:}

I am writing to you on behalf of the Wikipedia project (http://www.wikipedia.org/),
an endeavour to build a fully-fledged multilingual encyclopaedia in an entirely
open manner, to ask for permission to use your copyrighted material.

% The \ldots command produces dots in a way that will not upset
% the typesetting of the document.
\ldots

That said, allow me to reiterate that your material will be used to the noble end of
providing a free collection of knowledge for everyone; naturally enough, only if you
agree. If that is the case, could you kindly fill in the attached form and post it
back to me? We shall greatly appreciate it.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

I look forward to your reply.

\closing{Yours Faithfully,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]